# System cannot get past Ubuntu login after update

Tags: 14.04

After installing the latest Ubuntu update, I can't get past the Ubuntu login screen. The resolution is lower, the GUI items are larger,  and 
the projection (the screen-content) does not fit the screen.

When I try to log in, the screen gose black, gives some graphics flair-up, and crashes back down to the login interface. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Reset Unity

```
unity --reset
```

Reset Unity Launcher icons

```
unity --reset-icons
```

Reset Compiz

```
gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
unity --reset
```

log out and log in again

Comment: that didn't work.